# When do I use the word 'to' in front of a verb?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I have difficulties to understand when to use the preposition 'to' and when not. For example, I always write sentences like the following:

> They help you **to** explore the world.

I often get corrected that it's grammatically incorrect and the following is preferred:

> They help you explore the world.

Can someone shed some light on the grammar rule? Thanks!

Comment: Adding the ‘to’ makes it an infinitive, if I’m not wrong

Comment: A infinitive verb does not always need to be preceded by **to** . Google **bare infinitives**.